# Why does my TensorFlow NN model's predicted values have upper limit?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a neural network with three layers. I've tried using tanh and sigmoid functions for my activations and then the output layer is just a simple linear function (I'm trying to model a regression problem).

For some reason my model seems to have a hard cut off where it will never predict a value above some threshold (even though it should). What reason could there be for this?

Here is what predictions from the model look like (with sigmoid activations):

[image]

**update:**

With relu activation, and switching from gradient descent to Adam, and adding L2 regularization... the model predicts same value for every input...

[image]

Comment: what's your loss?

Comment: I'm using mean squared error for cost function. I'm going to try L2 loss to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: actually nevermind that, doesn't matter. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear layer regressing a single value will have outputs of the form

```
output = bias + sum(kernel * inputs)
```

If inputs comes from a `tanh`, then `-1 <= inputs <= 1`, and hence

```
bias - sum(abs(kernel)) <= output <= bias + sum(abs(kernel))
```

If you want an unbounded output, consider using an unbounded activation on all intermediate layers, e.g. `relu`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that relu was giving me the same predicted value always, but turns out I was doing sigmoid on my first layer then relu on second. Anyway, if I use relu for all my activations I get a weird problem where my cost function (mean square error) increases with each epoch instead of decreasing.

Comment: This is a very different problem. Is that loss for the training or evaluation set? If eval/test set, you're probably overfitting - consider adding regularization of some description or reducing the number of parameters (layers/nodes) of your network. If on the train set, I'd try, in order: normalize inputs, normalize labels, lower learning rate, different optimizer.

Comment: I switched from gradient descent to adam optimizer and implemented L2 regularization and I'm back to getting a decreasing cost function. But now my model just predicts the same value for every input...

Comment: Yeah not same question anymore, I feel like using relu, or some other activation function that doesn't restrict values to a certain range, is the answer to my question. Maybe I should make a new question for the issue I have now...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem concerns the generalization/expressiveness of the model. Regression is a basic task, there should be no problem with the method itself, but problem with the execution. @DomJack explained how output is restricted for a specific set of parameters, but that only happens for anomaly data. In general, when training parameters would be tuned so that it will predict output correctly.

So first point is about the quality of training data. Make sure you have large enough training data (and it is split randomly if you split train/test from one dataset). Also, maybe trivial, but make sure you didn't mess up input/output value in preprocessing.

Another point is about the size of the network. Make sure you use large enough hidden layer.